# Syncing .htaccess rewrites between different servers

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am working on a load balanced WordPress site and am using the Yoast plugin to allow the clients to add redirects to the .htaccess file via the staging admin site.

The problem is that this will only add the redirects to the .htaccess file in the staging admin project (the staging admin site is only on one server).

Is there a recommended way to keep the .htaccess files between the load balanced site in sync so that the redirects are added to each file?

Or is this something I will need to write a program to do?

** Solution Update **

Thanks to veNuker I was able to get a cron job running that copies the modified .htaccess over to the remote servers using rsync. I didn't realise that rsync only works if the file has changes, so this truly is a great solution.

My cron task looked similar to this:

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --progress /var/www/origin-website/html/public/.htaccess username@XXX.XXX.XX.XX:/var/www/destination-website/htdocs/public
```

The following [digital ocean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-copy-files-with-rsync-over-ssh) was a huge help.

Thanks again, hope this helps anyone else in a similar situation!

Comment: I never like to let users edit the .htaccess, especially if I wouldn't give them file level access and trust them to be able to use sftp. Why are you doing it on .htaccess level instead of in WP?

Comment: @janh The clients add redirects via a plugin on WP. They never see the .htaccess file, the plugin writes the redirects to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a cron job for it:

```
* * * * * rsync -avz /var/www/public_html/.htaccess root@<remote-ip>:/var/www/public_html/
```

Keep in mind it is not safe to use root user ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this seems like the best solution